# awk count number of fields and add accordingly

Tags: linux, scripting, sed, awk

I have the following file.csv

```
111111 | 111111 | 22222 | 44444 | 4445454 | 67554333 |
```

I can count the number of fields using the following

```
awk -F '|' '{print NF}' file.csv
```

in my database schema I have 33 fields, however some of the lines in my csv file has less than 33 fields therefore when I import the file, it complains about miss match.

using awk how can I go about adding NULL fields spreader by | in order to full up 33 rows

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add empty fields at the end of line:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{for(i=NF+1;i<=33;i++)$i=""}1' file.csv
```

Comment: A simpler version could be `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NF<33 {$33=""} NF>=33'` (no need to set the fields between `NF+1` and `33`, and the `NF>=33` prints the line).

Comment: @jfgagne Good idea. `'NF<33{$33=""}1'`

Comment: What does the 1 at the end ?  Implicitly true ?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/|/&/33;t;s/$/|/;ta' file.csv
```